# Code doesn't compile becasue of "not all paths return value" even though logically they do

Tags: c#, if-statement, recursion, return-value

Here is my Search method in the `BTree` class:

```
public bool Search(string val)
    {
        if (String.Compare(Value, val, false) == 0)
            return true;

        if (String.Compare(Value, val, false) < 0)
        {
            if (RightChild != null)
                RightChild.Search(val);
            else return false;
        }
        else
        {
            if (LeftChild != null)
                LeftChild.Search(val);
            else return false;
        }
    }
```

This code dosen't compile, since not all paths return value (all my returns are conditioned), even though logically they do.. I cant figure out how to solve this basic problem..
Maybe my entire approach is wrong?

Comment: so where is `Value` defined.., where is `RightChild` and `LeftChild` defined..? poor example of a question without posting all relevant code..

Comment: I think you meant to `return` the result from the `Search()` calls. i.e. `return RightChild.Search(val);` and `return LeftChild.Search(val);`

Comment: put a return before your Search calls

Comment: DJ KRAZE - obviously evrybody else understood what I was asking without looking at my entire class which is useless to understand the problem.
All the rest - thanks for your answer, it solved the problem.

Comment: I've edited your question a little bit. Since it's not about the binary search at all (as you said yourself) I've changed the title so that people having a similar problem can easier find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public bool Search(string val)
    {
        if (String.Compare(Value, val, false) == 0)
            return true;

        if (String.Compare(Value, val, false) < 0)
        {
            if (RightChild != null)
                return RightChild.Search(val); // added 'return'
            /*[REMOVED]else return false;*/
        }
        else
        {
            if (LeftChild != null)
                return LeftChild.Search(val);  // added 'return'
            /*[REMOVED]else return false;*/
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: In some cases `C#` can be stragne. Although you have all paths covered with `else`s you are forced to put another `return` at the end to satisfy the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Add return statements to the RightChild.Search and LeftChild.Search calls.  I assume that this is a member of some kind of Node class and these are recursive calls.